# solrCloud(9.5) integrates springboots, and adds user authentication, and there is no problem with queries, but the new one keeps reporting errors

Tags: solr

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsVGC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWpv9.png)

solrCloud(9.5) integrates springboots, and adds user authentication, and there is no problem with queries, but the new one keeps reporting errors ,what wrong I do not  konw

Comment: Please add the relevant information as text to your question - images aren't searchable, has bad accessibility, can't be copy-pasted. Also add details about what you've tried and what the difference is to your other endpoints if they work - i.e. what works and what doesn't.